# What is the benefit of Python being dynamically typed?

Tags: python, typing, strong-typing, dynamic-typing

I've noticed that, with programming experience, I increasingly code in a way that mimics static typing<sup>*</sup>:

- using Python's type hints along [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484), [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526), [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544), [PEP 586](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586), [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589), and [PEP 591](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591)
- checking object types when working interactively
- writing docstrings with typing info
- noticing that a lot of mistakes were caused by lax typing while coding
- noticing that, with increasing maturity, more and more features are added to Python that provide stricter typing options

On the other hand, I'm not really sure if I ever benefited from dynamic typing:

- Dynamic typing isn't really necessary for the interactive shell - is it?
- Doesn't save *much* time or keystrokes
- Python supports generics, if type mutability is desired

1. **What is the fundamental reasoning for Python being dynamically typed?**
2. **What applications does dynamic typing enable that would be impossible or much more difficult, were it statically-typed?**

<sup>* <sub>I mostly refer to one of the possible definitions of static vs dynamic typing revolving around the type being bound to the variable vs to its value (since, for an interpreted language, the definition via checking at compile vs runtime is not applicable).</sub></sup>

Comment: "Why" questions about language design are generally off-topic. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design -- our scope is limited to questions with answers that will solve a practical problem you actually face. Moreover, even were that not true, we explicitly try to avoid topics likely to cause "more heat than light" -- more argument than practical substance -- and this specific question is one that religious wars are fought over.

Comment: Maybe this interview with Guido van Rossum will help you: https://www.artima.com/articles/strong-versus-weak-typing

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I realize that, I was really looking for practical substance in the way of a couple of code examples and perhaps a link to a specification or such.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of practical examples or specification link would answer your question. A specification tells you what the language _is_, not the reasoning behind it being that way. And practical examples would be... what, code with and without typing, to compare keystroke count? What constitutes "enough keystrokes saved" to justify the difference is entirely in the eye of the beholder; the time spent iterating on getting type-correct/buildable code is harder to demonstrate, and likewise going to vary by author.

Comment: (I will note that over in the Clojure world, I've seen more than one shop try to switch to using [`core.typed`](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed) -- an extension to the language providing type enforcement, now [Typed Clojure](https://github.com/typedclojure/typedclojure) -- and later decide it wasn't worth the trouble and switch back).

Comment: @FrancoMorero Yes, that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Shame the other interview parts are 404'd... what I gather from the interview is, basically, that a dynamic language allows a more fluent development and testing, and that, at least in van Rossum's opinion, the static typing "bondage" is not as advantageous as some might think.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see.. so it's not a clear-cut decision, then. I had the feeling that I missed some Programming 101 lecture where this destinction had been made clear, and that now I'm missing some obvious use-case. That's helpful, thanks!

Comment: At the risk of starting an opinionated rant, a lot of folks worried about typing, I think, are worried about typing _done badly_. The C++ and Java worlds in particular have a lot of boilerplate -- code written just to satisfy the type system without other practical use, and systems whose design is heavily influenced by the need for that code -- without being able to make useful assertions that better type systems support ("must not be null", "must be a valid value for this enum type, but not specifically the unknown one", etc), souring a lot of people on the concept as a whole.

Comment: The academic world has come up with some much more powerful type systems -- Haskell's is a great example -- though that too tends to, by nature, change how people think about system design, thus being necessarily contentious.